# how to solve wordpress wp-admin cookie blocked error?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on wordpres site, site works good but whenever i try to login using wp-admin it shows me error called "cookies are blocked due to unexpected output" and i can see one of the text "password" return on left top area of wp-admin screen.I tried to change password from phpmyadmin but it does not works. can any one help me out for this.
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Debug info by adding following code in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

It will show you what code might by causing the issue.

Also read this thread please people with same issue have solved:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-log-in-cookies-are-blocked-due-to-unexpected-output?replies=37

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening after moving a multisite to a different domain (for dev purposes for instance) then make sure you edit the following line in your wp-config.php file and change the previous domain to the current one:

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'newdomainname.com');
```